# CMake error : Attempt to add a custom rule to output

Tags: ros, catkin-make, face-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,
I am trying to migrate the face_recognition package to catkin but I have lots of problems.
I tried with : http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild
but it doesn't work. So I create a new catkin workspace and I tried to add every folder one by one as if it was a new project. When I try to do a catkin_make I have this message :

```
CMake Error: Attempt to add a custom rule to output "/home/www/ros/devel/include/face_recognition/FaceRecognitionAction.h.rule" which already has a custom rule.
CMake Error: Attempt to add a custom rule to output "/home/www/ros/devel/share/common-lisp/ros/face_recognition/msg/FaceRecognitionAction.lisp.rule" which already has a custom rule.
CMake Error: Attempt to add a custom rule to output "/home/www/ros/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/face_recognition/msg/_FaceRecognitionAction.py.rule" which already has a custom rule.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Erreur 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

My Cmakelist.txt is like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(face_recognition)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
actionlib
  actionlib_msgs
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  #opencv2
  roscpp
  roslib
  rospy
  std_msgs
)
 add_message_files(
    FILES
    FaceRecognitionAction.msg
    #FaceRecognitionActionFeedback.msg
    #FaceRecognitionActionGoal.msg
    #FaceRecognitionActionResult.msg
    #FaceRecognitionFeedback.msg
    #FaceRecognitionGoal.msg
    #FaceRecognitionResult.msg
    #FRClientGoal.msg
 )

 find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

   add_action_files(
      FILES
      FaceRecognition.action
    )

   ## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
   generate_messages(
     DEPENDENCIES
     actionlib_msgs
     std_msgs
    )
     include_directories(  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
     add_executable(Fserver src/face_recognition.cpp)
     add_executable(Fclient src/face_rec_client.cpp)
```

Can somebody help me please?
thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187981/cmake-error-:-attempt-to-add-a-custom-rule-to-output/) by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2014-07-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-07-28**:
Please post your CMakeLists.txt

**Comment by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on 2014-07-28**:
I edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Don't name your message `FaceRecognitionAction.msg`.

This name conflicts with your `FaceRecognition.action` because when the action gets compiled to message files a message called `FaceRecognitionAction.msg` will be created and this new message conflicts with your `FaceRecognitionAction.msg`.

So, simple solution: Rename your message.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on 2014-07-28**:
I rename my action as FaceReco.action and it worked. but now I have a message :
/home/www/ros/src/face_recognition/src/face_rec_client.cpp:12:52: fatal error: face_recognition/FaceRecognitionAction.h : Any file or folder of this type.

I try to include a .h that I put in the folder include but I guess that's not where  I should put it?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-07-29**:
Sorry, I don't get your new problem from this description. What is the exact error message? What header files do you put in include. If include is the wrong place, where should header files go otherwise?

**Comment by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on 2014-07-29**:
The error message says that the file FaceRecognitionAction.h doesn't exist but actually it exists and it's in my include folder. I don't know where I should put it so the program can find it.
In the include file, I put all my headers. I don't know where else should I put them.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-07-29**:
Do you mean the FaceRecognitionAction.h that was auto created from your action? This one shouldn't be in YOUR include directory. This one should be in devel/include automatically.

**Comment by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on 2014-07-29**:
I think it's the FaceRecognitionaction.h auto created from my action that also generate messages. I clean the message folder so the message can be built automatically and try to buil again but I still have the error about the FaceRecognitionaction.h missing. My folder devel/include is empty.

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2015-03-24**:
I followed the actionlib tutorial. same problem with @RosFaceNoob. So when I first time compiled the Fibonacci.action, I commented out the add_action_files in CMakelist and copied the msg folder from devel/share to the package folder. Compiled successfully.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-03-25**:
@tianb03 I would recommend you to search for the true reason for your error. Your solution is not very nice and could possibly cause you some trouble afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you trying to port this package over to catkin? https://github.com/procrob/procrob_functional/tree/master/face_recognition

If looks like you're trying to call message generation on the generated message files from your action files - this is unnecessary, because the action generation already does it for you - hence the error you're seeing about creating a rule that already exists.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on 2014-07-29**:
Yes that's what I am trying to do. I just did a catkin_make, the generation is done automatically.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-29**:
In that case, you should probably leave the action files named as they are, and don't use add_message_files at all.

**Comment by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on 2014-07-30**:
When I try that, I still have the error about my FaceRecognitionAction.h that doesn't exist. I don't understand why it wasn't auto genrated.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-30**:
You may need to add an explicit dependency between the program you're trying to compile and the header generation, so that they're run in the correct order. Something like:

```
add_dependencies(your_program ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

**Comment by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on 2014-07-31**:
I add to my CMakeLists.txt :  add_dependencies(Fserver ${face_recognition_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
 add_dependencies(Fclient ${face_recognition_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
Now I have this error:
face_recognition.cpp:(.text._ZN3ros13serialization16VectorSerializerIfSaIfEvE5writeINS0_7OStreamEEEvRT_RKSt6vectorIfS2_E[void ros::serialization::VectorSerializer<float, std::allocator, void>::writeros::serialization::OStream(ros::serialization::OStream&, std::vector<float, std::allocator > const&)]+0xae): undefined reference to `ros::serialization::throwStreamOverrun()'
collect2: ld a retourné 1 code d'état d'exécution 
make[2]: *** [/home/www/ros/devel/lib/face_recognition/Fserver] Erreur 1
make[1]: *** [face_recognition/CMakeFiles/Fserver.dir/all] Erreur 2
make[1]: *** Attente des tâches non terminées....
make[2]: *** [face_recognition/CMakeFiles/Fclient.dir/src/face_rec_client.cpp.o] Erreur 1
make[1]: *** [face_recognition/CMakeFiles/Fclient.dir/all] Erreur 2
make: *** [all] Erreur 2

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-31**:
You probably also need to do `target_link_libraries(Fserver ${catkin_LIBRARIES})` in order to properly link against the ROS libraries.

**Comment by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on 2014-08-01**:
I am back to my first error: 
Linking CXX executable /home/www/ros/devel/lib/face_recognition/Fserver
[100%] Built target Fserver
Scanning dependencies of target face_recognition_generate_messages
[100%] Built target face_recognition_generate_messages
/home/www/ros/src/face_recognition/src/face_rec_client.cpp:13:43: erreur fatale:
 face_recognition/FRClientGoal.h : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
compilation terminée. (the file doesn't exist)
make[2]: *** [face_recognition/CMakeFiles/Fclient.dir/src/face_rec_client.cpp.o] Erreur 1
make[1]: *** [face_recognition/CMakeFiles/Fclient.dir/all] Erreur 2
make: *** [all] Erreur 2
Invoking "make" failed

I think I am in an infinite loop

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-01**:
That's a new error - notice that it's complaining about a new file. If FRClientGoal.msg isn't generated from an action, you may need to explicitly generate headers from it.

**Comment by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on 2014-08-01**:
FRClientGoal.msg should be generate from an action like all the other headers but it's not. that's the problem

**Comment by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on 2014-08-01**:
I add manually FRClientGoal.msg in the Cmakefile. it generatage a FRClientGoal.h file. I can compile the project but when I try to make a rosrun, I have a message that says that the executables are not found. They are in the folder /ros/devel/lib/face_recognition and it looks only in the package folder src/face_recognition. How can I tell him to look in another folder?

**Comment by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on 2014-08-01**:
Finaly I moved the executable in the right folder mnually but the program doen't understand the message FRclientGoal. what should I do ?
Thanks for your help

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-01**:
You should probably ask about your runtime problems as a new question, and include the full CMakeLists.txt.